# Laravel ClassLoader includes an incorrect/old file

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

in a laravel 4 aplication some weeks ago I created a workbench package:

```
/workbench/no-native/wizard
```

This package has a class called `Handler` in the path `/workbench/no-native/src/events/` declared like this:

```
<?php
namespace Wizard\events;

class Handler{

    ....
```

In order to dump-autoload via composer, I added it:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src/migrations",
        "src/controllers",
        "src/events",
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "NoNative\\Wizard\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

Well, with this structure the package worked very well. Yerterday, I had to move this package from `workbench/no-native` to `workbench/native`. The steps were the following:

1. Move the `wizard` dir from `no-native` to `native` dir.
2. Update paths and namespaces.
3. Update the package composer to target the new file structure.
4. Execute the following commands (in `native`, the new path):

   ```
   /home/user/public_html/my-app/workbench/native/wizard# composer update
   /home/user/public_html/my-app/workbench/native/wizard# composer dump-autoload
   ```

After finished, I notice that ***in my localhost instance the application works perfectly*** with the changes, but in my live server an exception is showed:

> **include(/home/user/public_html/my-app/workbench/no-native/wizard/src/events/Handler.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory file:**
>   /home/user/public_html/my-app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php line 382

I assume that the application still trying to load the Handler class from old path. Then, I ran the commands in order to "clean" or "optimize" the application:

```
# php artisan optimize
# php artisan dump-autoload
```

And the exception still there. The live server has the same code of my localhost instance, because both work with cloned sources via Github. I do not know  if I am missing something else. My last option is to create a new package via command, and then create the classes again. But before to do that, I would like to ask to you for alternative options.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you run the `php artisan dump-autoload` command from your live application root, or the live application workbench directory?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange, yes, I have ran [every command](http://cheats.laravel.com/) with not success. Some of them throws the exception before it ends.

Comment: Try composer dump-auto before artisan dump-auto ?

Comment: I think that this issue will not be solved via command. There is something else in some compiled file that is not get updated.

Comment: did you try to run php artisan clear-compiled?

Comment: @DarrylCoder, I am not sure if I did it, but I had to rollback the package with no solution because it took me too many hour than expected in tracking work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you updated your packagist repository. Many times it does not auto update while pushing code to github so try to force update it. After this try to clear composer catche and then run php artisan dump-autoload.

Comment: what does php artisan dump-autoload do, compared to composer dump-autoload?